# Error playing audio and animation to unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm building a game that wants my player to rise when the mat hits the mat and makes a noise.  I did this code in my playback source and whatever I did, only the mattress sounds and seismic animation I defined for it did not work.  That is, it runs only for the first mattress, and when it hits the second and third mattresses, only the first mattress shakes.  If I want to explain to other mattresses inside the player that (if my player tags the mattress) there is a lot of code.  And I do not want to be busy.
I also created a separate source called the trampoline and attributed it to all the mattresses.
I also entered this code for the trampoline source:

```
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D TagTrampolin)
        {
            if (TagTrampolin.gameObject.tag == "PlayerTAG")
            {
                MyAudio.PlayOneShot(AudioTrampolin);
                MyAnimation.Play("Anim_Larzesh");
            }
        }

        void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D TagTrampolin)
        {
            if (TagTrampolin.gameObject.tag == "PlayerTAG")
            {
                MyAnimation.Play("Anim_Stap");
            }
        }
```

(I also gave `GetComponent` to `MyAnim` and `MyAudio` resources, but I did not type it here because it took too long)
But when the player hit the mat, the game stopped and he made two mistakes that I do not understand.  I also translated them but did not say anything specific.
From the empty code `OnTriggerEnter2D` and
`void OnTriggerExit2D`
I used it, but it gave the same error again.

If anyone knows please help me because it is very important.  I apologize if I mispronounced or mispronounced a sentence because I can not speak good English.